# How do you deserialize a serialized lambda function in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments, lambda, bundle, serializable

I have a lambda expression:

```
val lambda: ((ArrayList<String>) -> Unit)
```

I put this into a Bundle as a Serializable, like so:

```
putSerializable(LAMBDA, lambda as Serializable)
```

How do I Deserialize the lambda back into the function type: "((ArrayList) -> Unit)" ?

I'm trying to get this to work:

```
            state.getSerializable(LAMBDA)?.also {
               val deserializedLambda: ((ArrayList<String>) -> Unit) = it
            }
```

"it" is Serializable. But I need to deserialize it somehow to get it back to being of type ((ArrayList) -> Unit), which is the type of the variable "changes".

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you need a cast: `it as (ArrayList) -> Unit`.

Comment: Yep it was as simple as doing a cast. Thanks, accepted as best answer.